# Redirect_to with string path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to redirect to a location based on a param on a submitted form.
If params[:route] = group , I want to redirect to groups_path.
I tried the following method to redirect but obviously enough the groups_path is a variable and not a string. How can I redirect based off the param?

```
redirect_to "#{params[:route]}s_path"
```

Edit:
realised I can redirect to the actual path but this doesn't seem like a very rails way of doing it.

```
redirect_to "/#{params[:route]}s"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
redirect_to send("#{params[:route].pluralize}_path")
```

But I'd rather write a wrapper-helper returning appropriate url helper based on the `params[:route]` value. `params[:route]` could potentially have any value and you may want to rescue in these cases.

Comment: I agree, hit the nail on the head.
Is it counted as a problem if someone tries to send themselves to another path, they will either get denied with authentication or hit a 404 page anyway. Why would I make it a helper?

Comment: would be even better if you use redirect_to send("#{params[:route].pluralize}_path") so you get the correct pluralization

Answer (score 2):

send can calls private method, therefore better is public_send

and instead "#{params[:route]}s" use "#{params[:route].pluralize}

```
redirect_to public_send("#{params[:route].pluralize}_path")
```